# How to find date clusters in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, grouping

I want to find clusters of dates in a table with the following structure:

```
patientID  | dt
---------- | ----------
1          | 2016-05-03
1          | 2016-05-05
1          | 2016-05-07
2          | 2016-07-12
2          | 2016-07-15
2          | 2016-07-18
1          | 2016-07-13
1          | 2016-07-14
```

Per SQL I want to find clusters of dates within 7 (or any other interval) days from the first date in this cluster. Normally the gap between two consecutive clusters is more than 7, so this problem can be ignored. The result should be like:

```
patientID  | min(dt)    | max(dt)    | count(dt)
---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------
1          | 2016-05-03 | 2016-05-07 | 3
2          | 2016-07-12 | 2016-07-18 | 3
1          | 2016-07-13 | 2016-07-14 | 2
```

My first approach doesn't work and it's clear why not (cannot group by aggregate), but I've no idea how to solve my problem:

```
select t0.patientID, min(t0.dt), max(t0.dt), count(*)
from tbl t0 
join tbl t1 on t0.patientID=t1.patientID and t1.dt - t0.dt between 1 and 7
group by t0.patientID, min(t0.dt);
```

Comment: don't want to join `generate_series(start::date,end::date,'7 days'::interval)`?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are two different problems.  The second problem -- finding clusters separated by more than 7 days -- is the easier problem to solve in SQL.  You can do this by using `lag()` to calculate the difference between dates, create a flag from the `lag()` and use a cumulative sum and aggregation:

```
select patientid, min(dt), max(dt), count(*)
from (select t.*,
             sum( (case when dt > prev_dt + interval '7 day' then 1 else 0 end)
                ) over (partition by patientid order by dt) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(dt) over (partition by patientid order by dt) as prev_dt
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by patientid, grp;
```

The first problem you describe requires a recursive CTE and the processing will be much slower.

Comment: This solved my problem. No need for a CTE. Thanks a lot!